# Find with _id not working in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have a collection named Releases that holds a subdocument named product.
My collection looks like this:

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("5b1010e4ef2afa6e5edea0c2"),
  "version": "abc",
  "description": "<p>abc</p>\n",
  "product": {
    "_id": ObjectId("5b100c9949f43c6b6f10a93f"),
    "name": "Product 1",
    "description": "<p>abc</p>\r\n",
    "image": "Product 1.png",
    "__v": 0
  },
  "releasedate": ISODate("2018-05-30T00:00:00Z"),
  "__v": 0
}
```

I am trying to find all releases associated to a specific product.

```
   var id = req.body.productId
   var query = {'product._id' : id};
   Release.find(query)
   .select('_id version description product releasedate')
   .sort({releasedate: 1 })
   .exec()
   .then(releases => {
     console.log(releases);
     res.status(200).json(releases);
   })
```

But it gives me an empty array if i console.log(releases)
I've been stuck with this for a while and asking u guys for help. What am i doing wrong. I read the documentation on https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/ and tried to apply that to my code but i cant get it to work.

My Schema looks like this:

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

   var Product = new Schema({
   _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   name: String,
   description: String,
   image: String,
   });
   module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', Product);
```

Comment: Are you sure that your id (`req.body.productId`) is correct and is an ObjectId or a string equals to `5b100c9949f43c6b6f10a93f `?

Comment: @rphonika Thank you for replying. yes, i double checked it

Comment: Maybe one solution will be to convert your id in ObjectId: `var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.productId)`.

Comment: This did the trick! thank you very much!

Comment: If you want you can answer this question and i'll mark it as the solution. Or i'll answer it myself with your solution.

Comment: The **only** reason you would have to actually manually cast to `ObjectId` is because your schema is incorrect. If you correct the schema then mongoose will actually do that for you. You should post the schema you have if you are unsure what to do.

Comment: @NeilLunn See updated answer :)

Comment: @LarsSuffys you don't need to put `_id` in schema model... `_id` will be   generated automatically...

Comment: I saw it. It's wrong. You don't need to cast at all. That's what I was telling you but you failed to understand.

Comment: okay guys, thanks for the help. i'll remove _id form my Schema model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `id` from string to mongoose `objectId`

```
var id = req.body.productId
   var query = {'product._id' : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.productId)};
   Release.find(query)
   .select('_id version description product releasedate')
   .sort({releasedate: 1 })
   .exec()
   .then(releases => {
     console.log(releases);
     res.status(200).json(releases);
   })
```